# Can same thread wait and run task simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, threadpool

I'm following [Walkthrough: Debugging a Parallel Application in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-parallel-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) from Microsoft documentation.
And from section about [Parallel Tasks window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-parallel-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#using-the-parallel-tasks-window-and-the-tasks-view-of-the-parallel-stacks-window) when hitting third breakpoint it clearly says:

> In this example run, notice that task 11 and task 12 are running on the same thread (show the Thread Assignment column if it is hidden).

[Tasks window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRhB3.png)
From "Tasks window" we see that task 11 is "Blocked" and task 12 is "Active"

If we navigate to task's 11 location which is "O" method we can see that it's blocked on line t5.Wait();

```
static void O(object o)
  {
    Task t5 = Task.Factory.StartNew(P, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    t5.Wait(); // tasks 11 blocked here
    R(o);
  }
```

and then by inspecting "Tasks window" we can see that same thread(27500) has two tasks: task 11, which is blocked by calling `t5.Wait()` and task 12 which is active and runs "P" method as a new task. But how it's possible that single thread has blocked task and runs another at the same time?

I've debugged this walkthrough several times and i succeed to repeat same behavior only once randomly. Other times i saw, as i thought, correct behavior where task with method "P" always runs in another thread.
[Tasks window local debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wft6I.png)

I thought, when thread calls task's "Wait" method, thread becomes blocked until tasks finishes?
What did i miss here?

Comment: `Task....StartNew` actually starts a new thread.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, that is not correct. It starts a new task, not a new thread. Tasks may be run on a different thread or the same thread. That the system manages that is part of the point of the TPL.

Comment: This from the documentation for [`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) seems to account for the behaviour you were told to expect and the inconsistent behaviour you're seeing: *"If the current task has not started execution, the Wait method attempts to remove the task from the scheduler and execute it inline on the current thread. If it is unable to do that, or if the current task has already started execution, it blocks the calling thread until the task completes."*

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, seems like this's a great example that Task.StartNew creates new task within same Thread. More info here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-wait-and-inlining/. Please add your comment as answer and refer to Stephen Toub's post as well, so i could accept it. Thank you for help!

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, a thread cannot wait and execute at the same time.

A thread is represents a OS resource with separate stacks and program counters. This means a thread can only do a single thing. If it is blocked, for example by a lock, it cannot do anything else.

But a task is not a thread. A task is simply an object on the heap. It has no separate program counter or stack, and it cannot do anything of its own. It needs a thread to run anything.

I'm not sure when tasks are counted as "blocked", but it most likely do not match the definition of a blocked thread. There is nothing fundamentally preventing a thread from being associated multiple tasks, but it can still only do one single thing at a time.

I would suggest opening the Threads panel to show all the threads. This will show all the threads in all processes, including call stacks for each.

Comment: "I'm not sure where you are seeing a single thread associated with multiple tasks at once"

Please check "Thread assignment" column from "Tasks window" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRhB3.png) image i've pinned.

Comment: @АлексейПавлов Made some clarifications.

Comment: This screenshot taken from Microsoft walkthrough, i also pinned link to it. And they point out to this case on purpose, don't think that this's wrong:

"In this example run, notice that task 11 and task 12 are running on the same thread (show the Thread Assignment column if it is hidden)."

Comment: Yes with @jmcilhinney help i found out great Stephen Toub's post (devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-wait-and-inlining) which's explains exactly my case. I was able to catch this behaviour again and by inspecting stack trace i could see that Wait method runs task by calling TryExecuteTaskInline in the same thread. Thanks for help